# how to change scrapy user agent without settings file

Tags: python, django, scrapy

I have implemented my spider via a script just like the main example:

```
import scrapy

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('h2.entry-title'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

        next_page = response.css('div.prev-post > a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

I run with:

> scrapy runspider myspider.py

How do I change the user agent if I don't have a setting or have create from startproject? As specified here:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html

Answer (score 2):

You can manually add a header in your request so you can specify a custom `User Agent`.

In your spider's file, when you request:

```
yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls, callback=self.parse, headers={"User-Agent": "Your Custom User Agent"})
```

So **your spider** would look like that:

```
class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://blog.scrapinghub.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(self.start_urls, callback=self.parse, headers={"User-Agent": "Your Custom User Agent"})

    def parse(self, response):
        for title in response.css('h2.entry-title'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::text').extract_first()}

        next_page = response.css('div.prev-post > a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse, headers={"User-Agent": "Your Custom User Agent"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `USER_AGENT` to the `settings.py` file:

```
USER_AGENT = "custom_user_agent"
```

You can change the `USER_AGENT` through `cmdline` too using:

```
scrapy runspider myspider.py -s USER_AGENT="custom_user_agent"
```

Comment: Since I am using django, is this the django settings.py ?

Comment: No, This is scrapy's settings.py.